# How to get nearby point of interest in android?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm to get all nearby "point of interest" for a given latitude/longitude within a given radius without giving any search key.

I started with `google place web api`. But this api gives desired data when using on web only, not on android. I tried using separate keys on android for same api, even though, the place web api didn't work on android any how. It always said on android, "invalid api key".

Then I moved to `google place android api`. But this gives data when we use their custom UI, not in any other ways. (But I just want to get location data, not data on google's UI. Since, I want to show POI on camera).

I thought a `GEO_DATA_API` may help me on android. But somehow it's giving me empty result.

Here is my code for GEO_DATA_API that gave me zero result:

```
Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, query, bounds, null)

                .setResultCallback(
                        new ResultCallback<AutocompletePredictionBuffer>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResult(AutocompletePredictionBuffer buffer) {
                                if (buffer.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                    for (AutocompletePrediction prediction : buffer) {
                                        PlaceResult placeResult = new PlaceResult();
                                        placeResult.setPlaceId(prediction.getPlaceId());

                                        placeResult.setName(prediction.getFullText(null).toString());
                                    }
                                }

                                //Prevent memory leak by releasing buffer
                                buffer.release();
                            }
                        }, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```